# how to use xpath to select a text if tabindex="0" follows an a tag

Tags: html, web-scraping, xpath

My xpath command cannot extract a text(post-title) from web html. Here is a complete web element example:

```
<a tabindex="0" href="https://newyork.craigslist.org/mnh/egr/7552398294.html" class="post-title"><span class="label">Project Architect</span></a>
```

I used a scrapy shell after cd to a scrapy project folder:

```
$scrapy shell 'https://newyork.craigslist.org/search/egr'
$response.xpath('//a[@class="post-title"]')
```

Any ideas on how to extract the text?

Comment: Can you share all your code including the link to the page you working on?

Comment: @Prophet I have edded more information. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
response.xpath('//a[@class="post-title"]/span/text()').extract()
```

Or

```
response.xpath('//a[@class="post-title"]/span/text()').get()
```

Comment: I have tried this soltion and I did not get any output. I have added more information - see above. Thanks

Comment: Can you try with .extract()? I edited de answer

Comment: for some reason none of the above worked.

Comment: What are you getting if you print the results?

Comment: I got back empty square brackets